# What are good writing newsletters to sign up for?

Tags: resources

What are some good newsletters writers can sign up for? I signed up for [Funds for Writers](http://www.fundsforwriters.com/) and [Worldwide Freelance Writers](http://www.worldwidefreelance.com/) because they have some excellent tips and advice for both freelance writers and fiction writers.  What would be other newsletters along these lines that I should sign up for?

Comment: Are you just looking for newsletters, or would blog RSS feeds count, too?

Comment: @Nathan Blogs would work too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like Randy Ingermanson's "[Advanced Fiction Writing](http://advancedfictionwriting.com/ezine/index.php)" monthly e-zine.

You can look at back issues of the e-zine to see if it fits the kind of newsletter you're looking for. He also writes a blog at the same site.

Answer (score 2):

Posted my OPML [here](http://www.workingstorage.com/Writing.zip).

It's a good mix of feeds.